# Unique over 2 columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 columns col1 and col2

INITIAL QUESTION:
*is it possible to make a constraint to not be able to add the same email two times in this columns, only using indexes?*

The Question has been edited to:
"*Is it possible to define a constraint so as to be unable to add the same email twice in these columns **for the same record**, using only indexes?*"

**But it is my fault, I did not give enough details.**
When I have a **unique** column. I can not repeat a entry in this column.
What I need is to expand this "unique" to a second column, so that any entry made in the first column, should not be possible entered to the second column at all.

I can do it using a external program by consequently adding the entries for this two columns in a array and always checking the array before entering something to this two columns. But the solution a joke, it is sub-optimal, because by extrapolation we do not need databases any more we can use arrays.

Is this possible using just mysql, or do I need "my array" ?

Comment: Have you tried to Google your title?

Comment: What do you mean? Is the second email address for person A allowed to be the same as the first or second email address for person B?

Comment: Column names like thing1, thing2, ... thingN are often a sign of a design that should have been implemented differently, because -- depending on who you ask -- the design may be a violation of the ["no repeating groups" rule of 1NF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202535/1695906) which makes things like this more difficult. Why are there two email columns?  The answer to that question may help shed light on appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today you allow 2 emails; tomorrow you will allow 3.  That begs for having a separate table.  Such will let you use `UNIQUE`.

A schema design rule:  Don't use multiple columns to implement an "array"; use a separate table.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can use `CHECK` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
  ADD CONSTRAINT email1_is_not_email2_CHK
    CHECK (email1 <> email2) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this with the `CHECK` option in the `CREATE/ALTER TABLE` statement, but only for MySQL since v8.0.16 and MariaDB since v10.2.1.

<sup>***Reference:** [13.1.20.7 CHECK Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) (MySQL Dev Documentation)* and [CONSTRAINT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints) (MariaDB KB)</sup>

## Example

### Create Table

```
create table emlchk
(
check (email1 <> email2),
emlchk_id int not null auto_increment,
email1 varchar(100),
email2 varchar(100),
primary key (emlchk_id)
)
```

### Insert First Records

```
insert into emlchk 
(email1, email2) 
values
('something@domain.com', 'something@domain.com')
```

Insert will fail with message:

> Check constraint 'emlchk_chk_1' is violated.

### Check Contents of Table

```
select * from emlchk
```

Yes, the table is still empty.

### Insert Valid Records

```
insert into emlchk 
(email1, email2) 
values
('something_one@domain.com', 'something_two@domain.com'),
('something_one_one@domain.com', ''),
('','something_two_two@domain.com')
```

...and verify:

```
select * from emlchk
```

...which returns:

> ```
> emlchk_id | email1                       | email2                      
> --------: | :--------------------------- | :---------------------------
>         1 | something_one@domain.com     | something_two@domain.com    
>         2 | something_one_one@domain.com |                             
>         3 |                              | something_two_two@domain.com
> ```

### Update Second Column with Same Data

```
update emlchk set email2 = 'something_one_one@domain.com' where email1 = 'something_one_one@domain.com'
```

Returns:

> Check constraint 'emlchk_chk_1' is violated.

### Update Second Column with Different Data

```
update emlchk set email2 = 'something_one_two@domain.com' where email1 = 'something_one_one@domain.com'
```

This seems to work.

## Complete Example

The complete example can be found on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbd1c58fc3a52f67e4a6a9c7f0596853).

Answer (score -3):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE KEY(email1,email2);
```

Comment: Err, no. This makes the combination of the two email addresses, and in that order, unique. So one could duplicate email addresses as long as the second email address was different.